# how to format the time in php

Tags: php, mysql

the time stored in mysql is like this style((1300774889), now i want to output it in php file like this style: 2011-3-23. how should i do? eg:the time field is $row->time

Comment: I suggest you to use the real SQL data types, such as DATE, TIME, DATETIME, TIMESTAMP, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function.

```
echo date( 'Y-m-d', $row->time )
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function.

Example:

```
date("Y-m-d", $row->time);
```

Demo:

http://codepad.org/WrCEhNQH

Answer (score 1):

Use the `date()` function, see [php.net date](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for reference.

For your example, this should work `$date = date("Y-m-d", 1300774889);`.